# html navigation bar with custom image backgrounds

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, navigationbar

I'm trying to make my own navigation bar in HTML and I want it to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nr2C.jpg

But I have no clue how to start or how to achieve this.
I have each of the tab images separated as this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb3RD.jpg

Each time a user click on a tab, the image of the tab come to the front.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Look into using css background images and a Sprite sheet.

Comment: having the image created with svg is another way of doing this, rather than overlapping images.you can then use css to control the layer within the SVG.